# ASMX Returning a pure string

Tags: c#, asmx

I have an ASP.NET web service (.asmx). My service is defined like the following:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = System.Web.Services.WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
  public string GetResult()
  {
    string result = "";

    int day = System.DateTime.UtcNow.Day;
    if ((day % 1) == 1)
      result = "odd";
    else
      result = "even";
    return result;
  }
}
```

Currently, if I call this service method, I get the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">even</string>
```

My issue is, I need to return just the string part. I do NOT want to return the wrapping XML. How do I do this with an .asmx?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it need to be an `.asmx` web service for this?  I mean, by excluding the SOAP envelope you're essentially saying "this is not a SOAP web service" as it is, so why not take it a step further and make it a regular `.aspx` page instead of an `.asmx` web service.

As a page, what you're trying to do would be trivial.  Remove all mark-up from the page, use `Response.Headers` to edit the response headers accordingly, `Response.Write()` to output your raw text, and `Response.End()` to close the response.

Comment: Genius. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @user208662: I now find myself wondering if the same thing can be achieved in an `.asmx` web method.  Part of me doubts it, but part of me doesn't.  Next time I find myself in front of my development environment I'm going to have to test it out and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @user: You should make an ASHX handler, not an ASPX page.  You don't need the overhead of ASPX.

Answer (score 2):

Use json

add the required attribute to your web service and your web method and you get what you want.

Web Service Attribute:`[ScriptService]`

Web Method Attribute:`[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`

Read a sample [Here](http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=494)

Comment: Unfortunately, that approach doesn't work :(. I still get the response in XML. Seems odd. I would expect it to be wrapped in Json. Other ideas?

Comment: Why? see the result of running example, http://www.williamsportwebdeveloper.com/BookQuery.html

Comment: Dave Ward has a great post about this:

http://encosia.com/2010/03/03/asmx-and-json-common-mistakes-and-misconceptions/

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to get rid of the XML part? The code which is generated by the proxy needs a common format so it can understand and read the data that is being returned.  Stripping the XML essentially makes your return data unreadable by the client proxy.

Comment: XML is unwanted if the client wants only JSON.